# using two different data-ng-view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, passport.js, ng-view

adminpage.html

```
<html><body ng-app = "myapp"
 <div data-ng-view/>
</body></html>
```

userpage.html

```
<html><body ng-app = "myapp"
 <div data-ng-view/>
</body></html>
```

After login, if you are admin, adminpage.html will be loaded. If you are normal user, userpage.html will be loaded. `data-ng-view for adminpage.html is very different with userpage.html`. How can I do that with angularjs, passportjs, expressjs?

Answer (score 0):

You should just have one index.html file that bootstraps your application and only one ng-view. Based on the role returned from your server-side authentication mechanism, you would then route the user to the appropriate route you set up with $routeProvider.